# Impossible to suppress a specific clang warning on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, clang, compiler-warnings

I have set -Wno-unused-parameter (and some others) compiler flag, and it is indeed passed to the compiler, but I'm still getting this warning:

```
clang++ -c -pipe -Wno-self-assign -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -Wall -W F/Library/Frameworks -o ../build/cobject.o src/cobject.cpp                                                     ^
src/cobject.cpp:102:68: warning: unused parameter 'client' [-Wunused-parameter]
void cobject::processNetMsg( int type, CNetMsg& msg, CClient& client )
                                                                   ^
```

Is it because `-Wall` is also specified? Shouldn't `-Wno-...` take precedence? How to tell clang to display all warnings except for some?

Comment: I would suggest (but not 100% sure) that you should put "-Wall -Wno-..." in that order, rather than turning something off (that probably is off by default anyway), then turning on "everything".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The warning arguments acts like toggles. When you do e.g. `-Wno-unused-parameter` you turn  off that warning, however later on the command line you do `-Wall` which turns it back on again. The order of the arguments matter.

So to solve it, place the off-argument *after* it's turned on.

Comment: Thank you! I thought `clang` is smarter than that (in terms of processing command line arguments) :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: trouble is *smarter* is subjective. The reason it act like toggles is that this way you can *override* arguments that you inherit from a "more global" level. So Clang is smart, just not the way you thought it was :)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I wouldn't find the opposite _smarter_. Say that you have `-Wunused-function -Wno-unused -Wall`; if the order does not matter, what would be the "smart" result for you? Sometimes we tend to assume that our biases are obvious.

Comment: confusingly enough, gcc acts differently. -Wno overrides -Wall regardless of order